# Set Application Expiration Date

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET application that I would like the user to be able to run for a fixed period, then have it switch to a partially restricted mode. I have the code in place to do that, as well as code to encrypt data. What I need is to be able to track the date the application is first used. And have the date saved somewhere and in a format that the user is not likely to be able to reset it. Is there a preferred way to do this, such as some obscure Registry key?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf96a1wz(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it 100 percent requires this, then you need to store the information in your server. This is quite hard to do. If it doesn't need to 100 percent high security, you can use Settings in your application, or the registry. Here is a good tutorial on using settings in your application: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/72654-using-settings/.
If you want to use the registry, then here is a good tutorial on that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85t3c3hf.aspx. Note that using the registry requires administrator privileges.

Comment: Thanks, and 100 percent security is not required, just trying to keep the honest folks honest. I know how to use settings files and the Registry, due to the nature of my app I opted to use the Registry for my app settings. So if I wanted to hide a date somewhere, is there a good place in the Registry to do it? I don't think having a value named "expiration" in the key for my application would be a good idea.

Comment: You could change the date to be a in an unledgible format, by adding 89, dividing by 12 and multiplying by 3, or something similar, and name it something that like "Unique ID"

Comment: Thanks William, hiding the date is not a problem, I have a strong encryption routine that will do that. My question is that I don't want this to reside in any of the Registry keys I created, the way my app works the user could delete them all and they will recreate themselves. So is there a preferred key to use?